# Updating info daily without copy and paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which I update every day in order to make some financial calculations. In this sheet there's a button that once clicked updates a specific financial data from the web. It brings the date from the last entry and the data itself, for example 31/01/2014 -> 10,27. What I want to do is to be able to click the button and update the dates and data automatically, without having to copy the update info and paste it in the list. 
My idea was to use the vlookup function to find the row which has the date of the respective day and to paste the value brought in by the refresh button. So I tried the following VBA script:

(in the code "Today" is the name I gave to the day's date (31/01/2014 above) and "DI" is the info I want to update (10,27 above)

```
Sub Test1()

Dim SearchDI As Range

Set SearchDI = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Range("Today"), Range("A:B"), 2, 0)

Range("DI").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("SearchDI").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

It didn't work.

Does anybody know what approach could I use to look for the present date in a list and copy the value on the cell next to it?

Comment: Not sure if there is enough info to go on there. On the surface it looks to me as thought you could use `=VLOOKUP(UPDATED_DATE;ARRAY;INFO;0)` rather than `=IF(TODAYS_DATE=UPDATED_DATE;VLOOKUP(TODAYS_DATE;ARRAY;INFO;0)`. Or does your `ARRAY` lose the previous values each day?

Comment: Yes that's the point, the array loses the previous values each day when updated, as the website I use to update the info only shows the data from the present day.

Comment: In that case, what you are trying to achieve probably cannot be done using a formula. Any formula that works on today's values will not work for historical values. The solution for you is to link the "update" button to a macro that does the VLOOKUP and pastes resulting values into the destination cells.

Comment: So, any ideas on how to write that macro? I have almost no experience with macros, but I suppose it wouldn't be that complicated...

Comment: If you understand the basics of programming then a good approach is to use `Record Macro` (on the Developer ribbon); do the steps you need to update the figures manually; and then edit the VBA code that the macro produces.